# Small circuits schematics that can teach you something

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, design-rules

I’m looking for small simple circuits where one could learn something interesting and new about electronics from it. Not just solving circuit examples for solving sake, but small circuits with basic components that one could actually feel to be useful.

Some examples:

- the voltage adder circuit with an op-amp
- the OR-Diode with two diodes
- AND/OR gates with mosfets
- voltage follower with an op amp
- Integrator with op amp and capacitor

I’m looking for small circuit designs, with basic components (no sensors), like those that could teach something very important about circuits.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no question. Please add one.

Comment: ... but check that it's [on-topc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: This is asking for solutions without questions. Try working the other way around. Think of something simple you want to do, then find a circuit that does it.

Comment: `learn something interesting and new` ... that varies from one person to next ... how will you choose the correct answer? ... you may not think that an answer points to something new, but someone else may think it's new ... that would make the answer "correct", but you would not think that it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a copy of the old National Semiconductor Quadzilla applications pamphlet. It has a great collection of circuits and descriptions. And the National Linear Applications data book. Both are online.

And there is a masterclass in op-ampery from Analog Devices where they made a lot of stuff for analog computing and low noise instrumentation.

Note: I can not find a download of Quadzilla and I have thought about putting them all in KiCAD and sharing. Or at least the LM324 section.

https://ia601607.us.archive.org/23/items/fe_Op_Amp_Applications_Handbook_Newnes_Walt_Jung/Op_Amp_Applications_Handbook_Newnes_Walt_Jung.pdf

Try this:  https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_nationaldaLinearApplications_29136087